# How to get rid of handler:{} and hibnerateLayzInitializer:{} values from JSON output?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using `Sprint Boot` to implement a `RESTful` service. I have one-to-many mapping between a `Category` and a `Product`. My service works fine but somehow I am getting some extra `json` values such as `handler:{}` and `hibernateLazyInitializer:{}` in the json. See below.

How can I get rid of these values ?

**JSON Output:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 201,
    "name": "PowerBook G4 Aluminium",
    "description": "PowerBook G4 Aluminium description goes here....",
    "listPrice": 800,
    "active": "Y",
    "category": {
      "id": 103,
      "name": "Laptops",
      "description": "Laptops description goes here....",
      "active": "Y",
      **"handler": {},
      "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}**
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 202,
    "name": "PowerBook G4 Aluminium",
    "description": "PowerBook G4 Aluminium description goes here....",
    "listPrice": 1550,
    "active": "Y",
    "category": {
      "id": 107,
      "name": "Other",
      "description": "Other description goes here....",
      "active": "Y",
      **"handler": {},
      "hibernateLazyInitializer": {}**
    }
  },

 // code removed for brevity
]
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_seq", sequenceName = "product_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "LIST_PRICE")
    @Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 2)
    private BigDecimal listPrice;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private String active;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    //default constructor
    public Product() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getListPrice() {
        return listPrice;
    }

    public void setListPrice(BigDecimal listPrice) {
        this.listPrice = listPrice;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", listPrice=" + listPrice + ", active=" + active + '}';
    }

}
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "category_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "category_seq", sequenceName = "category_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private String active;

    //default constructor
    public Category() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description=" + description + ", active=" + active + '}';
    }

}
```

**pom.xml dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Spring Boot Version:**

```
<version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
```

Comment: Got you a solution for the problem?